# Move ux.stackexchange.com posts to a different account

Tags: support, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

I have a stackexchange.com account that is registered with the following:

1. Stackoverflow
2. UX
3. Programmers

I have made multiple posts on the various sites but I'm only interested in transferring across my posts made in UX to another account that I have.

Is this possible?

**Update:**
Just to clarify I want to move my posts from one account to another, not to a different site!

Comment: How's that a duplicate @lostsock? The OP isn't asking about moving questions from one site to another, but about moving their questions from one account to another.

Comment: @Yannis I see, thanks. *retracted cv*. I highly doubt that mods will let you pick and choose which posts are merged to your account from another. Probably a all or nothing thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to contact Stack Exchange directly ("contact us" link in the footer). In your message, you should be very clear about:

- What account currently holds the questions,
- What account you want to move the questions to,
- Which specific questions you want moved, and
- Why you want to move them.

I can't promise you they'll honor your request, but if your reasons for moving the questions make sense they'll certainly consider it. Also, it might take a while before they get back at you.

Please note that while having multiple accounts is not forbidden, your accounts must not interact with each other in any way. Otherwise, you might find all your accounts suspended.